# How to dismiss a UISearchBar programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a `UISearchController` and a `UITableView`. When a cell in the `UITableView` is selected, I'm adding a black `UIView` above the whole screen with some subviews on it. It works just fine when the `UISearchController` is inactive. But when it's active, the `UISearchBar` shows above my black view.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray array];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:[MySingleton shared].barTintColor];
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
```

---

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -64, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myView.layer.opacity = 0.9;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

I've tried make it inactive before placing the view,

```
self.searchController.active = NO;
```

and add myView to a navigation controller's view

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:myView];
```

and still no luck. Any idea?

Comment: By dismissing you mean removing it or taking off control from it? or making it inactive

Comment: Making it inactive or  taking off control from it - any of it just to make it not showing above the black view. I cannot remove it, I need the search bar on its place.

Comment: What happens if you set: `self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = YES;`?

Comment: The search bar hides - and it's great, but somehow it remains a first responder, and a keyboard remains present.

Comment: I have just tried [self.searchController resignFirstResponder]; and still the same - the keyboard is shown.

Comment: I've reached the result with strange combo: I've added

    -(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    if(myView){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;}

and 

    [self.searchController setActive:NO];
    [self.searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = YES;
before placing the black view.

MikeAtNobel, thank you very much for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.searchController setActive:NO];
```

This is a property of SearchController as per [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/active) documentation, should do the trick

Comment: Sorry, but I use UISearchController, not the deprecated UISearchDisplayController, and the method is not applicable to it.

Comment: It should be the correct answer, but somehow it works wrong: the search bar's text is cleared, but the search bar remains above the black view.

Comment: cal `resignFirstResponder` after search base is cleared

Comment: check if it is being called by adding a breakpoint. If it is then their is a hack for it by adding a tapgesture to the view in `searchbarDidBeginEditing`which will force resign the search bar and removing the tapgesture in `searchDidEndEditing`

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that will allow you to insert a view above another view in the view hierarchy called: `- insertSubview:aboveSubview:`. Here's how you could use it:

```
if (self.searchController.searchBar)
    [self.view insertSubview:myView aboveSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
else
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Still no luck, sorry. I tried this and if (self.searchController.active) too, but the search bar is still above the view.